# kaptDebugKotlin crashes when building with Java Version 11 or higher

Tags: java, android, gradle, kotlin, kapt

I'm getting an IllegalStateException/NoClassDefFoundError when trying to run the command `./gradlew :data:test` on my project (https://github.com/guger/MoneyBook). This error does occur when I'm using a Java Version higher than 11. I'm not able to use the jdk bundled into the IDE, since robolectric requires Java 9 or higher, when testing against Android Q and Java 9 does not work as it provides it's version string in a format which is not recognized by robolectric.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to analyze: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/tools/javac/file/BaseFileObject
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.analyzer.AnalysisResult.throwIfError(AnalysisResult.kt:56)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:182)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:164)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:54)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:84)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:42)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:104)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:1558)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:359)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:689)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:562)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:796)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:677)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:389)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:676)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835) Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/tools/javac/file/BaseFileObject
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.javac.KaptJavaFileManager.shouldBeFiltered(KaptJavaFileManager.kt:69)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.javac.KaptJavaFileManager.list(KaptJavaFileManager.kt:49)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.ClassFinder.list(ClassFinder.java:737)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.ClassFinder.scanUserPaths(ClassFinder.java:674)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.ClassFinder.fillIn(ClassFinder.java:554)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.ClassFinder.complete(ClassFinder.java:299)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol.complete(Symbol.java:642)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$PackageSymbol.members(Symbol.java:1131)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symtab.listPackageModules(Symtab.java:834)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Enter.visitTopLevel(Enter.java:345)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCCompilationUnit.accept(JCTree.java:535)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Enter.classEnter(Enter.java:286)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Enter.classEnter(Enter.java:301)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Enter.complete(Enter.java:577)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Enter.main(Enter.java:561)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.enterTrees(JavaCompiler.java:1066)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.AnnotationProcessingKt.doAnnotationProcessing(annotationProcessing.kt:66)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.AnnotationProcessingKt.doAnnotationProcessing$default(annotationProcessing.kt:35)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AbstractKapt3Extension.runAnnotationProcessing(Kapt3Extension.kt:230)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AbstractKapt3Extension.analysisCompleted(Kapt3Extension.kt:188)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.ClasspathBasedKapt3Extension.analysisCompleted(Kapt3Extension.kt:99)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM$analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration$2.invoke(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:96)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:106)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration$default(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:81)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:555)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:82)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.messages.AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.analyzeAndReport(AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.kt:107)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.analyze(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:546)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:177)
        ... 23 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.tools.javac.file.BaseFileObject
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:436)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
        ... 52 more
```

Does anyone experience a similar behaviour when running Android Projects on Java 11/12/13?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is due to the lacking support of JDK 13 in Gradle 5.x.
Gradle 6.0 will support Java 13 (https://docs.gradle.org/6.0/release-notes.html).

Until then, there's no other possibility than waiting.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue recently regarding to JDK9.
I used this library which solved the problem:

```
"com.github.pengrad:jdk9-deps:1.0"
```

Comment: Well, but actually my compiler does not find `BaseFileObject`, not `Generated`...